# How to print the pgd and stack_start values of processes in linux?

Tags: c, process, linux-kernel

I'm trying to print a processes pgd and start_stack values but I have an issue when I read values from the mm pointer of each process. The end goal is to create an LKM that will go through the processes and print a title, the pgd, stack_start and stack_canary values. I have a feeling I need to lock something in order to view the mm data but I can't find what I need to do for that. Any help in the right direction would be very helpful. The following code reads the process information:

```
      void read_proc(){

  struct task_struct *p;
  struct mm_struct *mm;
  int len = 0;

  for_each_process(p) {
    task_lock(p);
    mm = p->mm;
    down_write(&mm->mmap_sem);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Proc Q4: Name: %s Stack Canary: 0x%X Start Stack: 0x%X PGD:
    0x%X\n",p->comm,p->stack_canary, mm->start_stack), mm->pgd->pgd);
    up_write(&mm->mmap_sem);
    task_unlock(p);
  }

}
```

Comment: after a little research I think I need to lock the task and use down_write, when I try to read the mm->[value] areas my LKM locks up my linux box.

Comment: When you reference mm to print out the values, do &(mm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every process in the process list has a mm struct. try testing if mm is null before trying to reference these values.

P.S. CPSC 457 homework?

Comment: haha yea, I've been meaning to add that as the answer, good catch